# Eclipse Juno crashes after creating Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash-reports

My Eclipse Juno crashes every single time after creating Android Project. After I click on the `Finish` Button in the `"New Android Project"` wizard, the `javaw.exe` uses 100 % CPU-Time.

I was waiting for around 30 minutes, but Eclipse didn't react at all - so I had to kill the process every time.

The result is a broken useless project file.

```
OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64
Java: 7 JDK x64
Eclipse: Juno 4.2.0
```

A fresh installation of Eclipse didn't resolve the problem. I also reinstalled the Android SDK and ADT-Plugin, but nothing happened. It's only Android-Projects that are causing the problem.

Am I using a known incompatible configuration, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Check your environment variable

-Try Changing the eclipse workspace

-Give the 32 bit JDK a try

You can also try checking out the windows log.  Windows Event Viewer might have caught the exception that Eclipse might have thrown.

Last while not ideal, you can try creating your project via the command line:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html#CommandLine

Comment: It seems, that JDK 64bit caused the problem. I also copied the JRE-Folder into my Eclipse-Folder to avoid conflicts with my other Java-Applications. (Eclipse prefers the runtime in the JRE-Subfolder and ignores JAVA_HOME.) =)

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing Memory settings for Eclipse. Follow steps from [here](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html)

Quoted from the link.

> Increase Eclipse's Memory Settings The Android project is large enough
>   that Eclipse's Java VM sometimes runs out of memory while compiling
>   it. Avoid this problem by editing the eclipse.ini file. On Apple OSX
>   the eclipse.ini file is located at
>
> /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini
>   Memory-related defaults (as of Eclipse 3.4):
>
> -Xms40m
>   -Xmx256m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>             Recommended settings for Android development:
>
> -Xms128m
>   -Xmx512m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m